# Scrapy File Not Found error on Images Pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

This scrapy script downloads some files and it works file for other items but it gives **file not found** error on one specific link.
Here is my images pipline class:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'image_names': item["image_names"]})

    def image_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
        checksum = None
        for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
            if checksum is None:
                buf.seek(0)
                checksum = md5sum(buf)
            width, height = image.size
            path_img = r'full/%s' % response.meta['image_names'] + ' ' + str(random.sample(range(1, 10000), 1)[0]) + " " + str(random.sample(range(
                1, 10000), 1)[0]) + str(random.sample(range(1, 10000), 1)[0]) + str(random.sample(range(1, 10000), 1)[0]) + str(random.randint(1, 10000)) + '.png'

            my_file = Path(r'/images/full/%s' %
                           response.meta['image_names'] + '.png')
            if my_file.is_file():
                path_img = r'full/%s' % response.meta['image_names']

            path = path_img  # **Here Changed**

            self.store.persist_file(
                path, buf, info,

                meta={'width': width, 'height': height},
                headers={'Content-Type': 'image/png'})

        return checksum
```

The image name for this specific item is **Kiaitre Trekking Poles for Hiking Collapsible – 2pc Pack Hiking Poles with Double Lock Design, Aerospace Grade 7075 Aluminum Trekking Sticks for Hiking, Walking
and Camping(Full Sets of Accessories)** and the error is as follow

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/full\\Kiaitre Trekking Poles for Hiking Collapsible – 2pc Pack Hiking Poles with Double Lock Design, Aerospace Grade 7075 Aluminum Trekking Sticks for Hiking, Walking and Camping(Full Sets of Accessories) 6476 4954670675302757.png'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well it's really in the error messages itself, that directory/file doesn't exist. Make sure you have the correct path to the item.

Comment: it is correct and it works for every other title. Then I tried to replace some characters from the title like "–" and the brackets "()" and it worked fine. I don't understand why these are causing the problem. Can you help with that?

Comment: @IbtsamCh no clue